# Use select count in relation Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have query:

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM uptime WHERE server_id = {$row['server_id']}";
```

And I have model Uptime with relation server:

```
public function server() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\server');
}
```

How with relation I can do `select COUNT(*)` and group by?

I think that:

```
Uptime::with('server')->groupBy('server_id')->select('count(*)');
```

or How?

Comment: Upload::select(DB::raw('COUNT(*) as count'))->with('server')->groupBy('server_id');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways,

Try:

Method 1:

```
Uptime::with('server')
->groupBy('server_id')
->count();
```

Method 2:

```
Uptime::with('server')
->groupBy('server_id')
->select(\DB:Raw('count(*) as count'))
->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this one out

```
Upload::select(DB::raw('COUNT(*) as count'))
->with('server')
->groupBy('server_id')
->get();
```